# Find the top N countries with highest GDP during tome period

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have a table with the following columns: country_id, country_name, continent, expenditure, date(yyyymmdd), population.
I want to find the n top (3 for example) countries with the highest expenditure for each day during time period (20170101 - 20170107).

```
SELECT DISTINCT country_name, expenditure 
FROM  expend_per_day
GROUP BY date
HAVING date BETWEEN "20170101" AND "20170107"
LIMIT 3;
```

But i dont get what i want, it shows me the first 3 rows.
I want that for each day to see 3 countries with the most highest expenditure and the expenditure it self.
Do you have any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Use ```ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `date`)```. *I want to find the n top (3 for example)* What output do you need if 3rd and 4th country have the same expenditure value?

Comment: There is no same values, so i dont have problem with that.
May you explain where i need to write or how to use the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `date`) ?

Comment: *There is no same values* ?? There exists unique index by `(date, expenditure)`? If not then duplicates **may** exist. Of course, the probability is low, but above zero, and the query **must** take this into account.

Comment: The expenditure is unique, so i dont have any repetition. and the values are decimal numbers.

Comment: *The expenditure is unique* There exists unique index by this column? if not then it is not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `date` ORDER BY expenditure DESC) rn
              FROM expend_per_day
          --  WHERE `date` BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170107' 
            )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
```

If there exists more than one row with the same expenditure for the same date as for 3rd row then indefinite row from these duplicated will be selected.